# Get number from android SMS app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-keypad

I am working on android app that is combined from two seperate app, a keyboard and the app itself - I want to make a button in the keyboard s.t onClick the app will be opened (a button to open the app but in the keyboard) - for that I have 2 questions :

1. Is that possible?
2. In case it is possible - how can I get the number that the user is texting to? is there any way to "extract" it from the context and pass it as an extra on the intent to open the app?

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Different keyboards are different. Even if you find out how to add your button to some specific keyboard app, there is no way you can add your custom button to all the keyboard apps in the world.

As for finding out the SMS number, I seriously doubt that, but I've never developed a keyboard myself, so unfortunately I cannot help here.

Comment: You missunderstood me on the keyboard stuff but I kinda thougt some of it through already...
Tnx alot anyway